# How to suppress errors in az devops cli

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

Can I suppress the error message from az devops cli in some way?

Ex.
If I run this command and no project with that name exists I get an error:

`az devops project show --org $Organization --project $ProjectName`

**ERROR: TF200016: The following project does not exist: project-name. Verify that the name of the project is correct and that the project exists on the specified Azure DevOps Server.**

That's ok, but if I want to put the result from that command into a variable, I still get the error message written in the console.
Can I get rid of that in some way?

Comment: `2>$null` silences stderr output; `2>&1` merges stderr output into the success output stream, which means it too will be captured when assigning to a variable - see the conceptual [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) help topic

Comment: You can suppress the error message by redirecting the error output to null when running the command just like mklemdnt0 mentioned. Use `2>/dev/null` to achieve this, like:


*result=$(az devops project show --org $Organization --project $ProjectName 2>/dev/null)*

Also the link in the comment above is really good for learning the concept.

Comment: Thank you both for the help. ```2>$null``` did it for me.